# FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION

Tags: apex, validation, lookup-filter

I am receiving the attached error when I am trying to save an Account record.

Background: -
I have created a Multi Select picklist field on Account (Service Partner Type).

On Implementation partner (a) field on Project object, I need to add a criteria so that it filters by "Service Partner Type" includes/contains "Certified Implementation Partner (CIP)". But, I couldn't as it is a multi select picklist value.

Therefore, I have created a checkbox on Account and used a WFR to make it true when Service Partner Type= 'Certified Implementation Partner (CIP)' and I have added this checkbox field as a lookup filter criteria.

Also, whenever Service Partner Type field on Account is populated/updated, Service Partner Type field on Project is populated with the same values. (I used Apex(appended below) to make populate a multi-select picklist field values onto another multi-select picklist field).

Now, when I edit an Account, I receive a field filter validation error appended below.

> Error:Apex trigger SCAccountTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: SCAccountTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a2d32000002TCXyAAO; first error: FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.: [Implementation_Partner_Lookup__c]: Class.SCGlobalUtilsClass.UpdateServicePartner: line 543, column 1

```
public static void UpdateServicePartner(List<Account> acclist){
    Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();
    Map<String, String> spmap = new Map<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> spsmap = new Map<String, String>();
    for(Account acc: acclist){
        accId.add(acc.Id);
        system.debug('accId::::::::::::::::'+accId);
    }
    if(!accId.IsEmpty()){
        system.debug('accId::::::::::::::::'+accId);
        for(account a: [Select id, Project_Name__c, Service_Partner_Type__c, Service_Partner_Specialty__c from Account where Id IN: accId]){
            System.debug('a.project name:::::::::::::::'+a.Project_Name__c);
            if(a.Service_Partner_Type__c!= null){
                spmap.put(a.Id, a.Service_Partner_Type__c);
            }
            if(a.Service_Partner_Specialty__c!= null){
                spsmap.put(a.Id, a.Service_Partner_Specialty__c);
            }


        }
    }
    if(!accId.IsEmpty()){
        List<pse__Proj__c> project = new List<pse__Proj__c>();
        for(pse__Proj__c p: [select Id, Service_Partner_Type__c, Service_Partner_Specialty__c, pse__Account__c from pse__Proj__c where pse__Account__c IN: accId]){
            if(p.Service_Partner_Type__c == null && p.pse__Account__c!= null){
                p.Service_Partner_Type__c = spmap.get(p.pse__Account__c);
                system.debug('p.Service_Partner_Type__c::::::::::::::::'+p.Service_Partner_Type__c);
            }
            if(p.Service_Partner_Specialty__c == null && p.pse__Account__c!= null){
                p.Service_Partner_Specialty__c = spsmap.get(p.pse__Account__c);
                system.debug('p.Service_Partner_Specialty__c::::::::::::::::'+p.Service_Partner_Specialty__c);
            }
            project.add(p);
        }
        if(!project.IsEmpty()){
            update project;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of help you want?

Comment: How do I overcome this FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION with modifying the lookup filter?

Answer (score 7):

Why you are getting this error?

> You are trying to update a lookup field which has a Look Up filter
>   added to it. And the value you are providing to that field does not
>   match the Look up filter criteria set on this Look up field.

**If you could identify what is the look up criteria and what value you are inserting in code then you can resolve the problem.** Find out and this API name in your implementation `Implementation_Partner_Lookup__c`. Either you make the code compatible with that field filter criteria or change the filter criteria (this in not recommended).

What is lookup field filter?

> Below is a stack exchange question link which explains the fact very
>   clearly. 
>   [Difference between dependent lookup and lookup filter](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117409/difference-between-dependent-lookup-and-lookup-filter)